# How to activate a function if an action has completed a set number of times?

Tags: javascript

Below is a script allows the user to move forward and back through questions. If the user comes to the last question and clicks the next button I want the page to go to finished.html. Currently on the first click the program brings the user to this.

```
var actual = 0; // select by default the first question

$(document).ready(function() {
    var number_of_question = $('.question').length; // get number of questions
    $('.question:gt(' + actual + ')').hide(); // Hide unselect question

    $('#nextQ').click(function() {
        if (actual < number_of_question - 1) {
            changeQuestion(actual + 1); // display select question
        }

        if (actual = number_of_question) {
            //alert("Finished");
            window.location.href = 'finished.html';
        }
    });
    $('#previousQ').click(function() {
        if (actual) {
            changeQuestion(actual - 1); // display select question
        }
    });
});

function changeQuestion(newQuestion) {

    $('.question:eq(' + actual + ')').hide(); // hide current  question
    $('.question:eq(' + newQuestion + ')').show(); // show new question
    actual = newQuestion; // memorize actual selection
    $('#question_number').html(actual);
}
```

Comment: `actual === number_of_question`

Comment: [Here is a working codepen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/jmLDd)

Answer (score 0):

You need `actual === number_of_question`, right now you are just assigning that value to `actual`

Comment: @moss I agree with Pointy, you should just use 'else'

Answer (score 0):

Two problems - as pointed out by others the confusion between equality and assignment, but also an edge case error: `actual` will count from 0 to `number_of_question-1` so you should have:

```
if (actual === number_of_question-1){
  //alert("Finished");
  window.location.href = 'finished.html';
}
```

Comment: I think it also needs to be `else if`, because on the last iteration `actual` will have been incremented *before* that test. In fact it really just needs to be `else`; no test is necessary.